# How to get access to Microsoft.Phone.Control in a Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library

I need to create a library for WP 8+ Apps that will recognize touches and gestures (and storing info about that). Is there a way to do this using Portable Class Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can include `Windows.Phone.Controls` (in my case from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Libraries`) since it is supported on a PCL with the `Windows Phone 8.1` subset.